# Using module's own objects in __main__.py

Tags: python, program-entry-point, init

I’m trying to access a module’s data from inside its `__main__.py`.

The structure is as follows:

```
mymod/
    __init__.py
    __main__.py
```

Now, if I expose a variable in `__init__.py` like this:

```
__all__ = ['foo']
foo = {'bar': 'baz'}
```

How can I access `foo` from `__main__.py`?

Comment: Up up up! I've had trouble with this numerous times, it's very disappointing to see such obvious behaviour not work the way one expects.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to either have the package already in `sys.path`, add the directory containing `mymod` to `sys.path` in `__main__.py`, or use the `-m` switch.

To add `mymod` to the path would look something like this (in `__main__.py`):

```
import sys
import os
path = os.path.dirname(sys.modules[__name__].__file__)
path = os.path.join(path, '..')
sys.path.insert(0, path)
from myprog import function_you_referenced_from_init_file
```

Using the `-m` switch would like:

```
python -m mymod
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18536602/208880) for more discussion.

Comment: adding `sys.path.append(os.getcwd())` before `from mymod import foo` worked perfectly, thanks

Comment: I think this relies on one executing the package from the parent directory. In this case, `python mymod`.

Comment: `sys.path.append( os.path.dirname(__file__) )` will add the directory of the file being executed to the sys.path

Comment: Note, however, that before the call to `sys.path.insert()` the directory containing `__main__.py` is in the sys.path which makes all modules adjacent to `__main__.py` a top-level module rather than namespaced under `__main__.py`'s package. In the event that the package contains a module name that is the same as a stdlib module, then the module provided by the package will be chosen before the stdlib module. It may be better to use `sys.path[0] = path` instead (overwrite the default path so that only the package's namespace is in the sys.path).

Answer (score 4):

The issue I run into the most with this type of thing is that I often want to run the `__init__.py` file as a script to test features, but these should not be run when loading the package. There is a useful workaround for the different execution paths between `python <package>/__init__.py` and `python -m <package>`.

- `$ python -m <module>` executes `<package>/__main__.py`. `__init__.py` is not loaded.
- `$ python <package>/__init__.py` simply executes the script `__init__.py` like a normal script.

## The problem

When we want `__init__.py` to have an `if __name__ == '__main__': ...` clause that *uses* stuff from `__main__.py`. We can’t import `__main__.py` because it will always import `__main__.pyc` from the interpreter’s path. (*Unless*…we resort to absolute path import hacks, which can cause a lot of other mess).

## <del>The solution</del> A solution :)

Use two script files for the module’s `__main__`:

```
<package>/
         __init__.py
         __main__.py
         main.py
```

---

```
# __init__.py

# ...
# some code, including module methods and __all__ definitions

__all__ = ['foo', 'bar']
bar = {'key': 'value'}
def foo():
    return bar
# ...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from main import main
    main.main()
```

---

```
# __main__.py

# some code...such as:
import sys
if (len(sys.argv) > 1 and sys.argv[1].lower() == 'option1'):
    from main import main()
    main('option1')
elif (len(sys.argv) > 1 and sys.argv[1].lower() == 'option2'):
    from main import main()
    main('option2')
else:
    # do something else?
    print 'invalid option. please use "python -m <package> option1|option2"'
```

---

```
# main.py

def main(opt = None):
    if opt == 'option1':
        from __init__ import foo
        print foo()
    elif opt == 'option2':
        from __init__ import bar
        print bar.keys()
    elif opt is None:
        print 'called from __init__'
```

---

The imports in `main.py` are probably not ideal in the case we are running from `__init__.py`, as we are reloading them into the local scope of another module, despite having loading them in `__init__.py` already, but the explicit loading should avoid circular loading. If you do load the entire `__init__` module again in your `main.py`, it will not be loaded as `__main__`, so should be safe as far as circular loading is concerned.

Answer (score 3):

The `__init__` module of [a package](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages) acts like members of the package itself, so the objects are imported directly from `mymod`:

```
from mymod import foo
```

Or

```
from . import foo
```

if you like to be terse, then read about [relative imports](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references). You need to make sure, as always, that you do not invoke the module as `mymod/__main__.py`, for example, as that will prevent Python from detecting `mymod` as a package. You may wish to look into [`distutils`](http://docs.python.org/distutils/examples.html).

Comment: I wanted to make the module directory executable.

Comment: Yeah I've tried these suggestions and they didn't work for me.

Comment: When I use `from . import foo`, I get a `ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package`, and `ImportError: No module named mymod` otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

If you run the module with `python -m mymod` then code in `__main__.py` will be able to import  from the rest of the module without having to add the module to `sys.path`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the first answer to be useful (i.e., hacking `sys.path`), but with the addition of `pathlib` in Python 3.4, I found the following code to be much more simple and Pythonic:

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path

# You don't need to .insert(), just append
sys.path.append(str(Path(__file__).parent.parent))
```

Answer (score -2):

Module directory structure is as follows:

```
py/
   __init__.py
   __main__.py
```

__init__.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
#
# __init__.py
#

__all__ = ['foo']
foo = {'bar': 'baz'}
info = { "package": __package__,
         "name": __name__,
         "locals": [x for x in locals().copy()] }
print(info)
```

__main__.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
#
# __main__.py
#

info = { "package": __package__,
         "name": __name__,
         "locals": [x for x in locals().copy()] }
print(info)
from . import info as pyinfo
print({"pyinfo: ": pyinfo})
```

Execute the module as a script using the `-m` flag

`$ python -m py`

```
# the printout from the 'print(info)' command in __init__.py
{'name': 'py', 'locals': ['__all__', '__builtins__', '__file__', '__package__', '__path__', '__name__', 'foo', '__doc__'], 'package': None}
# the printout from the 'print(info)' command in __main__.py
{'name': '__main__', 'locals': ['__builtins__', '__name__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__doc__', '__package__'], 'package': 'py'}
# the printout from the 'print(pyinfo)' command in __main__.py
{'pyinfo: ': {'name': 'py', 'locals': ['__all__', '__builtins__', '__file__', '__package__', '__path__', '__name__', 'foo', '__doc__'], 'package': None}}
```

Comment: This is your answer? How about a little bit of context or description to go along with what you are doing
?

Comment: This is a giant and ugly hack. Copying the variables through locals? HAHAHA sorry, but this was really funny.