# Python: modules and packaging - why isn't __init__.py file executed before __main__.py?

Tags: python, module, python-module

I have a python program that is entirely contained in a directory with the following structure:

```
myprog/
├── __init__.py
├── __main__.py
├── moduleone.py
└── moduletwo.py
```

I would like to be able to package this and distribute it so that another developer can do `pip install -e /path/to/git/clone/of/myprog` and can then import myprog in his own programs and do cool stuff with it.

I would also like to be able to run myprog at the command line as follows:

```
PROMPT> python myprog
```

When I do this, I expect python to execute the `__main__.py` module, which it does. However, this module makes references to some functions that are declared in `__init__.py` and which need to be available both when the program is run at the command line and when it is imported by another program. However, I'm getting the following error:

```
NameError: name 'function_you_referenced_from_init_file' is not defined
```

Do I have to import these functions into `__main__.py` somehow?

I tried a simple example as follows:

```
PROMPT> cat myprog/__init__.py
def init_myprog():
    print 'running __init__.init_myprog()'

PROMPT> cat myprog/__main__.py
import myprog
print 'hi from __main__.py'
myprog.init_myprog()

PROMPT> ls -l myprog
total 16
-rw-r--r--  1 iit    63B Aug 30 11:40 __init__.py
-rw-r--r--  1 iit    64B Aug 30 12:11 __main__.py

PROMPT> python myprog
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/Users/jon/dev/myprog/__main__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import myprog
ImportError: No module named myprog
```

Comment: To whoever is voting to close the question -- if it's that stupid and simple, maybe you could just explain it to me in a couple of seconds?  I tried to learn from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411293/using-modules-own-objects-in-main-py but am still having trouble.

Comment: You have to import everything except builtins, so the answer is a pretty obvious "yes".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Do I have to import these functions into `__main__` somehow?

Yes.  Only items in `builtins` are available without an import.  Something like:

```
from myprog import func1, func2
```

should do the trick.

If you don't have `myprog` installed in the normal python path then you can work around it with something like:

```
import sys
import os
path = os.path.dirname(sys.modules[__name__].__file__)
path = os.path.join(path, '..')
sys.path.insert(0, path)
from myprog import function_you_referenced_from_init_file
```

Which, quite frankly, is horrid.

I would suggest going with [MartijnPieters suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18537751/208880) and put the `-m` on the command line, in which case `__main__.py` can look like:

```
from myprog import function_you_referenced_from_init_file
```

Comment: This looks great, but it doesn't work on my machine.  I have tried two or three different variations of importing and I always get "ImportError: No module named myprog"

Comment: @JonCrowell: Then you don't have the myprog module installed, so Python doesn't find it. Look at packaging and developing: http://guide.python-distribute.org/ http://www.scotttorborg.com/python-packaging/ Quick hack: Add the directory above myprog to PYTHOPATH.

Answer (score 15):

The `__init__.py` is only loaded when you are import the *package*. You are instead treating the directory as a *script*, by executing the directory.

You can still treat the package as a script, instead of the directory however. To both treat the directory as a package *and* as the main script, by using the `-m` switch:

```
python -m myprog
```

Comment: I tried that, and now get a `No module named myprog`. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16637428/relative-import-in-python-3-not-working#33195094) seems to indicate that treating a directory as a package *and* a script are bad practice. Thoughts?

Comment: The answer states a personal opinion. Several standard library modules, plus popular packages such as `virtualenv` and `pip` support being run as a script. I personally appreciate and use this functionality. If you are getting a *No module named Foo* error your module can't be imported either; are you sure it is available on your Python path?

Answer (score 3):

So, having looked at the other responses and not being thrilled, I tried:

```
from __init__ import *
```

from my `__main__.py` file.

I suppose it doesn't allow you to refer to the module by name, but for simple cases it seems to work.