# how to import my custom module into a python IDE like Spyder and run my module?

Tags: python, package, anaconda, spyder

I'm pretty new to packaging scripts and I have an issue understanding how to run my code after converting it to a package!
I've developed a script with proper files and functions and used the setup tools to convert it to a package. Suppose a simple module named "Simulation_Package" with __ *main*_ _.py as:

```
def main():
    print("running the simulations")
    do stuff 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I installed the package in an Anaconda environment and when I use the Anaconda powershell prompt, I can run my script with no issues using:

```
python Simulation_Package
```

and it automatically runs my module and gets me the outputs which in this case prints "running the simulations"

When I use Spyder as an IDE, while I can import the package and Spyder recognizes my package, I cannot run the script. I have no idea how to run it actually. Call the **main** also returns an error:

```
import Simulation_Package
Simulation_Package.main()

AttributeError: module 'Simulation_Package' has no attribute 'main'
```

Any idea how to run the code in Spyder?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11567272/15649230

Answer (score 0):

Try using pip rather than conda. I suggest you to use pip for packages, conda sometimes behaves abnormally

Comment: I installed the package using Pip... I am referring to post-installation issue, reading the package in an IDE